# What is a simple/decent way to encrypt cookie in ASP.NET Core without using IDataProtector?

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-core

I am trying to understand how to encrypt contents of cookies in ASP.NET Core 2.1.

If I am using the `IDataProtector Protect` method to encrypt contents of a cookie, I have read that the `Unprotect` method will fail decryption if website  is moved to a different server, running in a server farm, Azure, etc.
If that is true and I don't want to use Redis (or moving keys around), and be able to use a simple method to encrypt contents how would I go about this?

This is my current code (using the IDataProtector):

```
    public static void SetEncryptedCookie()
    {
        var cookieData = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "a", "123" },
            { "b", "xyz" },
            { "c", DateTime.Now.ToString() },
            { "UserID", "unique-number-789" }
        };

        CookieOptions options = new CookieOptions
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(90)
            ,HttpOnly = true
            ,Secure = true
            ,IsEssential = true // GDPR
            ,Domain = ".example.org"
        };

        // _dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector("somepurpose");
        string protectedCookie = _dataProtector.Protect(cookieData);

        // IHttpContextAccessor _accessor
        // write cookie to http response 
        _accessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("mycookie", protectedCookie, options);

        // retrieve encrypted cookie contents.
        // ##### this will fail in server farms.
        var cookieEnc = _accessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["mycookie"];
        var cookieDec =  _dataProtector.Unprotect(cookieEnc);
    }
```

Comment: If you run more than just a single instance of your application, you will [have to configure data protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) so that all instances share the same configuration and are able to work with each other. You don’t necessarily need Redis for that but you _will_ have to configure this.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to avoid. From that link it says "Keys have a 90-day lifetime by default. When a key expires, the app automatically generates a new key and sets the new key as the active key." - if I want to expand my cookie Expiry date to e.g. 400 days and move site to a different server, it will require a lot of management, moving keys etc.

Comment: You cannot really avoid that if you want to keep the protection in place.

Comment: I understand. In this particular case, the cookie just contains some non-meaningful numbers to an outsider - that's why I want to go with something that is 'good enough' (yes I know, bad philosophy in encryption).

Comment: For those interested, I got feedback on SE Crypto: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/62489/is-rfc2898derivebytes-random-c

Answer (score 0):

At `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` do

```
DirectoryInfo SharedKeysDataProtectionDirectory = new DirectoryInfo("shared/KeysDataProtection/Directory");
services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName("WebFarmSharedAppName")
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(SharedKeysDataProtectionDirectory);
```